# Google recaptcha not working in Ionic application in IOS

Tags: ionic-framework, recaptcha, ionic4

I'm trying to use google recaptcha V2 in Ionic application. It works in web version, but there is empty space in IOS application.

There are no errors in console. Only blank space. Here is HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/fallback?k=6LfHfpUUAAAAAE4DUxvzZo7Og5l3anNY5wQzrRzd&amp;hl=en&amp;v=v1550471573786&amp;t=40055" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 302px; height: 422px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use domsanitizer to bypass security?And make sure that you enabled External Links (Associated Domains).

Comment: actually I use NgRecaptcha module. I inspect HTML and see that iframe